# Building .NET Standard and asp.net core together

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, .net-standard

I have a small solution with a asp.net core 3.1 and some .net 2.0 standard libraries. My pipeline fails with following:

> [error]C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.201\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3032,5):
>   Error MSB4216: Could not run the "GenerateResource" task because
>   MSBuild could not create or connect to a task host with runtime "CLR4"
>   and architecture "x86".  Please ensure that (1) the requested runtime
>   and/or architecture are available on the machine, and (2) that the
>   required executable "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.201\MSBuild.exe"
>   exists and can be run.

This is my pipeline:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: 'Frontend/VendorFormAPI/VendorFormAPI.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
    feedsToUse: 'select'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Building solution'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '$(solution)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Publish project'
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: true
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    projects: '$(solution)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Drop artifacts to container'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Is it not possible to build this?

Comment: You can try to add `/ t: Restore` to the argument in dotnet build task without using nuget restore.Or try the workaround in this similar [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61663658/why-is-msbuild-exe-missing-in-c-program-files-dotnet-sdk-3-1-201-causing-azure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was due to a windows form project in the solution.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here,  would you please accept it as the answer? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)

Comment: So what did you do to that project?

Answer (score 0):

I built the .net standard project independently from the .net framework (windows forms) and reference the dll.